# Unable to find errors - Turbo C

Tags: c++

I am making a simple program to add two numbers. I've done everything correct but somehow it's showing an error.

I am using TurboC for windows7 64bit (downloaded from [filezilla](http://sourceforge.net/projects/turbocforwindows-9/))... I've also used devcpp but but there its showing error in using void main()... Why this is so? **Why it is not working?**

**Also, can anybody suggest some good software for programming console-based for projects C, C++, etc.?**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
clrscr();
int num1=0,num2=0;

//printing hello world
//printf("Hello World!");

printf("Enter number 1 : ");
scanf("%d",num1);
printf("Enter number 2 : ");
scanf("%d",num2);
int num3 = num1+num2;
printf("The sum of %d and %d is %d",num1,num2,num3);
getch();
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You don't need a better software, you need to read a book about the C language.

Comment: Looks like it uses pretty old C standard and does not allow you to declare variables in the middle of a function.

Comment: I know C language and have also used Turbo C in my school and there it just works pretty fine. They have windows xp and earlier versions installed in there machines. It's just with the case of Windows7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your `scanf()`. When accepting values, you must add the `&` before the variable. The unary `&` returns the address of the variable next to it, and `scanf()` then stores the value at that address. But note that you do not need to use `&` in `printf()` unless you actually want to print the address.  In short, change your `scanf()` 's to

```
scanf("%d",&num1);
```

and

```
scanf("%d",&num2);
```

Here's your working code code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

int num1=0,num2=0;

//printing hello world
//printf("Hello World!");

printf("Enter number 1 : ");
scanf("%d",&num1);                 // see here
printf("Enter number 2 : ");
scanf("%d",&num2);                 // and here
int num3 = num1+num2;
printf("The sum of %d and %d is %d",num1,num2,num3);

}
```

The error with `void main()` is that it is no longer accepted. On older versions like TurboC, you can use `void main()`, but the standard clearly states that we should not use void for `main()`, instead you should use `int main()`.
Read this for reference

[What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

And, don't use `<conio.h>`. It's not supported in the standard. If you want to clear the screen, add the header file `<stdlib.h>` and use `system("cls");`

Regarding a replacement for `getch()`, you can just use `getchar()`. ( although in some programs, you will have to use two or more `getchar()`'s )

There's one thing you should know, and that is that both TurboC and DevC++ are outdated.

You should probably get Code Blocks.

You get the "Declaration not allowed here" error because prior to C99 ( your IDE TurboC runs on an older version than C99 ) , variables had to be declared at the beginning of a block. You can use [Declaration not allowed here error in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611062/declaration-not-allowed-here-error-in-c) as reference

Comment: thank you... you said conio.h is not supported in standard then how can I clear my screen?

Comment: there is one more problem... while assigning num 3 in line 15 it's showing an error "declaration is not allowed here"... how to resolve that?

Comment: @RaunakHajela , Move the `int num3` to the begining of the program, and use `num3 = num1 + num2 ;`

Comment: that I already did and it's working, I am just asking why it's not working like I did before?

Comment: Thanks sir. Now, I am running same program in CodeBlocks and it's showing this error "Can't find compiler executable in your configured search path's for GNU GCC compiler". Now, what to do?

Comment: @RaunakHajela , Take Settings -> Compiler -> Toolchain Executables  and click Auto Detect. If it doesn't work that means you probably haven't installed a compiler, or you installed it in a different path.

Comment: It's not working. Will you help me how to install a compiler in my system?

Comment: @RaunakHajela , For Windows 2000/XP/Vista/7 Try [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/13.12/Windows/codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup-TDM-GCC-481.exe/download) or [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/13.12/Windows/codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe/download) . For any other OS, visit [this](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26) and download the appropriate one and repeat the steps I gave you in the earlier comments. Make sure to download one with a compiler.

Comment: tried but not working.... getting same error "Can't find compiler executable in your configured search path's for GNU GCC compiler".. :-/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73764/discussion-between-arun-a-s-and-raunak-hajela).

Comment: @RaunakHajela , lets move this to chat. Come [Here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73764/discussion-between-arun-a-s-and-raunak-hajela) . Give me a reply over there when you reach there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only focusing on the error:

```
printf("Enter number 1 : ");
scanf("%d",&num1); //use & for input
printf("Enter number 2 : ");
scanf("%d",&num2); //use & for input
```

Answer (score 1):

**When you use `scanf()`, you must provide the address of the variable you write to using &.**

```
scanf("%d",num1);
```

should become:

```
scanf("%d",&num1); //add the & to refer to the address
```